# What would be a good laptop for running Ubuntu

Tags: laptop, ubuntu

I am in the market for a new laptop, and I was wondering if anyone knew of a good laptop for less than $400 that world have decent performance (preferably at least an Intel i3) and would work well with Ubuntu.
I will be using it for programming, surfing the web and writing documents. 
 Thank you for your suggestions

Answer (score 1):

I just took the most inexpensive computer I could find (€300 without an OS), and had no severe problems over the past 3.5 years. Use it as a development web server; on travels also as office computer.

I´ts an Asus K53U

- 15" wide screen glare display, full keyboard, Ethernet and WLAN g, a Kensington Lock, SD slot, 3*USB, VGA and HDMI output, DVD writer
- not *too* loud or heavy, and **it´s a breeze to exchange hardware components**.
- innards: AMD Fusion C50 (a little slower than an i3, but best performance per Watt), 2 GB RAM and a decent battery.
- The machine sometimes freezes for a minute or so when I open too many tabs in Firefox and have Kruzader running, but that´s about it. Not a single emergency boot in all the time.

The machine even survived a few (physical) crashes:

- life-hacked the power socket (after a 4ft drop to a stone floor)
- replaced the HDD with an SSD in no time (after the same drop)
- only the new DVD drive does´t really fit into the case; keeps popping open from time to time. (Yup: I actually killed my coffee cup holder.)

Answer (score 1):

I believe any i3 laptop should work with Ubuntu
Ubuntu is not so demanding in system so find any cheap or even refurbished laptops on newegg bhphotvideo moneyexchange